# Get element click on inside an SVG Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have two nested `<svg>` elements as follows:

```
<svg id="main_svg">
    <svg data="business" id="something">
        <rect>
            // Code for rectangle
        </rect>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

How can I get the id of the `<svg>` tag inside `main_svg`?

I tried the `contextmenu` event handler with `this.id` but it always returns `main_svg`:

```
$("svg").contextmenu(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

How can this be done? Are there any better approaches? I am happy with either events: `onclick` or `contextmenu`.

Comment: Why cant you do $("#something").on("click", function( {} )) ?

Comment: @labago because the ID is generated dynamically

Answer (score 2):

You can use the jQuery function `$('svg').find("> svg")` to find every direct child-`<svg>`-element of an `<svg>` element.

```
$('svg').find("> svg").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(id);
});
```

See the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kyjn6z87/

Comment: Can a or operator be used within find function?

Comment: What do you mean by "or operator" in this context?

Comment: Well the tags inside main_svg are dynamically generated and can be either SVG or PATH elements. Is there a way that I can select the element onclick irrespective of whether it's SVG or PATH?

Comment: You can use a comma-separated selector: `$('svg').find("> svg, > path");`